# Was macht ein Gyrosensor?

Tags: meaning, noun

Eine Suche auf Wikipedia resultiert in einer Weiterleitung zu [Beschleunigungssensor](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beschleunigungssensor). Nach weiterer Suche findet man auch diese Seite auf Wikipedia: [Gyroskop](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreiselinstrument). Im (online) Duden gibt es das Wort *Gyrosensor* aber überhaupt nicht und man wird auf *Gyroskop* weitergeleitet.

Durch die Wortherkunft und das oben Genannte handelt es sich bei einem "Gyrosensor" auf jeden Fall um Drehbewegungen.

Kann nun ein "Gyrosensor" auch Beschleunigungen messen, wie Wikipedia es als Weiterleitung angibt, oder kann er nur Drehgeschwindigkeiten messen?

Comment: Scheint mir eine Marketingfrage zu sein, keine sprachliche. Frag doch den Hersteller, was er darunter versteht.

Comment: Ich stimme dafür diese Frage zu schließen, weil es hier nicht um die deutsche Sprache geht. Zum einen lässt sich die Bedeutung des Wortes leicht ergoogeln, zum anderen ist »Gyrosensor« kein deutsches Wort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wie soll ich nun das aufgezeigte Problem bewerten? Kann ein "Gyrosensor" auch translatorische Beschleunigungen messen?

Comment: @Qbyte: Nein, es erfasst Drehbewegungen. Aber das ist keine Fragestellung der deutschen Sprache und daher in diesem Forum fehl am Platz. »Gyrosensor« ist ein griechisch-lateinisches Mischwort, das hat nichts mit Deutsch zu tun. Und sein Einsatzbereich sind Mobiltelefone und andere technische Geräte, also ebenfalls nichts, das auch nur ansatzweise etwas mit deutscher Sprache zu tun hat. Deine Frage ist an sich durchaus berechtigt, aber sie ist weder in einem Forum für Münzsammler, noch in einem Forum über Seidenmalerei noch in einem Forum über deutsche Sprache richtig platziert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn ich mir nur den Wikipedia-Artikel zu [Gyrometer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrometer) so anschaue, gibt es da viele Begriffe für verschiedenartige Dinge, die aber grundsätzlich das gleiche tun, nämlich eine Drehbewegung zu erkennen bzw. zu messen. Diese werden entsprechend alle *Gyrosensor* oder *Gyrometer* genannt.

Dabei gibt es verschiedene Bauarten:

- [Gyroskop](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreiselinstrument) Mechanischer Kreisel, bei dem die Abweichung von der Ursprungslage, also der Drehwinkel gemessen werden kann
- [Drehratensensor](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehratensensor) Sensor anderer Bauart, bspw. als Laser-/Faserkreisel oder mikromechanisch, der die Drehrate bzw. Drehgeschwindigkeit zurückliefert

Die Drehbeschleunigung kann man messen, wenn man zwei axiale Beschleunigungssensoren auswertet.

Answer (score 0):

Antwort: Ein Gyrosensor misst lediglich Beschleunigungen. wie genau ist auf Wiki nachzulesen, man kann zum Erfahren der verwendeten Kräfte einen sich drehenden Fahrradreifen in die Hände nehmen und kippen. Die daraus entstehenden Kräfte verwendet der Gyrosensor/Gyroskop zur Ermittlung der Lage eines Systems.

*Geschwindigkeitsmessungen ohne GPS-Modul oder Raddrehzahlen (mit dem Wissen des Raddurchmessers und des Schlupfs) sind unmöglich, außer durch das Integrieren der gemessenen Beschleunigung nach der Zeit.*

Wie die Kommentatoren erfolgreich festgestellt haben, geht es hier nicht um den Sachverhalt translatorischer Bewegungen. Was ich mit dieser Erklärung bezwecken wollte, war dem Autor der Frage zu erklären, dass es keinen reinen Geschwindigkeitssensor geben kann.

Ob es jetzt Gyroskop oder Gyrosensor heißt, ist mir nicht bekannt. Da vertraue ich auf den (online) Duden.

Comment: Es geht hier um Drehgeschwindigkeiten von Körpern im Allgemeinen, nicht um translatorische Bewegungen (für die GPS hilfreich wäre) oder für Drehbewegungen/Drehzahlmessungen von Rädern im speziellen (für die es geeignetere Sensoren gibt). Deshalb halte ich die Antwort für mehr irreführend als hilfreich.

Comment: Ich stimme Raketenolli zu. Nebenbemerkung: Die Beschleunigung muss man nach der Zeit integrieren v(t) = v_0 + integral(von: 0, nach: t, über: a(t) * dt)

Comment: Danke, meine Antwort war tatsächlich missverständlich. Mit den neuesten Änderungen sollte klar werden, was meine Intention war.

Mfg